# What is the connection between Key and Peele's 'Continental breakfast' and the movie 'The Shining'?

Tags: comedy, the-shining

I've seen the Key and Peele's sketch named 'Continental breakfast' a dozen times to say the least. It seems to me that they're focusing on how a man's fantasies can be over-enthusiastic at times. But I can't get a full interpretation of the sketch! But yet it's tantalising, as I can at least get the feel that something completely unorthodox is taking place (like most other K&P sketches!)

I've read some pages where people have commented that it's connected with the movie 'The Shining'. Now, it's embarrassing, but I actually haven't seen the movie. And hence am unable to perceive the theory.

Can someone give a short, self-explanatory jist so that I can understand what's happening?

Comment: Without spoiler I can tell you that the room 237 is a room in the movie "the shining" in which things happened (not in the book).

Comment: "Now, it's embarrassing, but I actually haven't seen the movie." I feel like, if you wanted to know the connection between the two, that would be the obvious place to start.

Comment: @M.Polo Yeah, you can also give a full answer. I won't mind! Right now I'm giving home exams ;)

Comment: @M.Polo With "full answer" he probably meant an *actual* answer rather than just a longer comment. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the references that I found:

#### 1. Room 237

When Jordan Peele's character walks into the hotel, the concierge tells him that he will be staying in room 237. This is a direct reference to the movie where [room 237](https://theshining.fandom.com/wiki/Room_237) plays a major role, all the bad stuff happens there.

#### 2. The continental breakfast room

This looks like a reference to the ballroom scene from the movie. The main character enters the room from a door on the left of the screen and the first thing they do, is talk to the waiter. The positioning is the same:

[image]

I also think the music that starts playing when he enters this room is the same one that was playing in the movie.

#### 3. The black and white picture

This one is obvious

[image]